# How can I perform a Chord on a touchpad in Minesweeper?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, minesweeper

Pressing left and right mouse button together is an important skill in minesweeper. This performs what is known as a '[Chord](http://www.minesweeper.info/wiki/Chord)' - uncovering all unmarked squares surrounding a number. The problem is, it's impossible to do with a touchpad.

If we touch the pad with 2 fingers, that's right click. 3 finger that's middle mouse button.

Can the shortcut for performing a 'Chord' be changed? Or is there another way I can perform the chord using a touchpad?

Answer (score 3):

You have tagged this question with [minesweeper](/questions/tagged/minesweeper) and [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10), but since Windows 10 doesn't ship with Minesweeper, I'm assuming you're talking about *Microsoft Minesweeper*, which you can download from the Microsoft Store.

In Microsoft Minesweeper, there are multiple ways to perform a chord:

- Double click/tap
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click/tap
- (Touchscreen only) tap

Note that other games of Minesweeper may use different ways to simulate a chord. For example, in http://minesweeperonline.com/ you simply press the <kbd>Space bar</kbd> key instead without clicking.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, you could solve this with [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

The following script will bind/remap mouse left and right click to keys <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> on the keyboard:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Minesweeper
1:LButton
2:RButton
#IfWinActive
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work for Minesweeper. It also won't change how the touchpad operates at all, so you can continue to use it for other actions.

For more information, see this guide: [Remapping Keys - Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).